# win7 - Выбрал через msconfig.exe booting in safe mode и получил Black screen of Death

Tags: bsod

и теперь, чтобы я не выбирал в меню по f8, во время загрузки кратковременно появляется надпись: "kernel the system is booting in safe mode - minimal services which network" и всё, черный экран с курсором, ничего не появляется, клики и комбинации клавиш не срабатывают.

Никакие решения BSOD с куросором из гугла не помогли. Я считаю это последствие изменений настроек загрузки в режиме защиты от сбоев с ограниченным набором служб в msconfig.exe

Как вернуть их обратно через реестр или файлы?  Система не грузится, зайти в msconfig я больше не могу...

Answer (score 0):

Решение - загрузиться с liveCD или установочного диска в консоль по Shift+F9. Там выбрать диск Цэ 
C:
затем на нём выполнить команду, убирающую из дефолтной загрузки safe boot:
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot

После чего система загрузится, и можно будет опять запустить msconfig, чтобы вернуть остальные изменённые пункты в состояние по умолчанию (Обычная загрузка)